# Magento 2 Custom Customer Account Link Created but that related phtml is coming with out navigeation links on left side?

Tags: magento2, customer-account, phtml, navigation

Actually I created A Custom Customer Account Navigation link by using This xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="custom-link" after="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">My Custom Link</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">frontname/controller/action</argument>                    
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

It Created The "My Custom Link" at the navigation links list but when I click on that link the corresponding phtml is opening in new page which is not containing customer navigation links at all on left side.How can I display that phtml beside the navigation links same like other link phtml.

Comment: See http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150399/dashboard-links-not-showing-my-custom-form-in-magento-2/150401#150401

Comment: in which xml file you have set Above code ?

Comment: customer_account.xml in my custom module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create **frontname_controllername_action.xml** file in `view/frontend/layout` of your module add below code to it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
        <action method="setPageTitle">
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Your Title</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Modulename\Block\Blockname" name="custompage" template="Vendor_Modulename::custompage.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```