# Custom Customer Account Link related page is not having navigation links on left side: Magento 2

Tags: magento2, frontend, customer-account

I have a custom module where I have added some custom links in the customer's account.
The custom page in the customer account's links redirects to a new page on clicking a particular link. I have also created the new page, but the issue is that the new page is not a part of the customer account page anymore but instead is a completely new page in Magento frontend.

I have added the link as,

in layout/customer_account.xml

```
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-my-quotes-link" after="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">path/to/link</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">My link</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

My layout file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout = "1column" xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation = "urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="customer_account"/>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
        <action method="setPageTitle">
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">My Title</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name = "content">
        <block class = "Path\To\Block\Class" name = "name" template = "Vendor_Module::my.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        <block class = "Path\To\Second\Block\Class" name = "name1" template = "Vendor_Module::second.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

So as above, when we click on "My link", it displays a custom page that directs to a new custom page. However, in the new page, there are no customer account's links.
How can I achieve this? Please help.

I have referred these links:
[Magento 2 Custom Customer Account Link Created but that related phtml is coming with out navigeation links on left side?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150846/magento-2-custom-customer-account-link-created-but-that-related-phtml-is-coming)

[Dashboard links not showing my Custom Form in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150399/dashboard-links-not-showing-my-custom-form-in-magento-2/150401#150401)

But they don't seem to work for me.

Comment: Make Your Page Layout to 2column-left or 2column-right  @manini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this changes in your layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout = "2column-left" xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation = "urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="customer_account"/>
// code goes here ***********
</body>
```